# How to take mojibake and figure out what the original character set was?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, mojibake

I have some data that is valid UTF-8.  However, parts of it, while still valid UTF-8, are obviously not originally UTF-8.  They also aren’t UTF-8 encoded Latin-1 either.

How can I figure out what the original charset of these parts are, so that I can recover useful information?  Or should I simply discard them as corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

There are mojibake converters out there. One open-source option is https://github.com/dekellum/mojibake:

```
gem install mojibake
require 'mojibake'
mapper = MojiBake::Mapper.new
mapper.recover( 'â€œquotedâ€�' ) #=> '“quoted”'
```